# Django corrupts uploaded wav files, while mp3 are fine?

Tags: angularjs, django, file-upload

I have a problem when uploading wav files to Django. Here is my view function that handles the file uploads:

```
def handle_upload(self, request, filename, format=None):

    file_obj = request.FILES['file']
    file_obj.name = str(request.user.id) +'_'+ file_obj.name  
    path = default_storage.save('my/path/'+file_obj.name, ContentFile(file_obj.read()))
    file_url = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, path)
    return Response(file_url,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The above code works good with mp3 files, however it corrupts wav files. It also corrupts images.

On the frontend side I am using an angular module that handles the upload: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Here is the frontend code:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)" accept=".mp3, .wav" class="upload" >
```

JS controller:

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function(file, errFiles) {
    $scope.f = file;
    $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];

    if (file) {
        api_service.upload_file(file).then(function(data){
            $scope.recording = data.data;
        })
    }
}
```

JS service definition:

```
    'upload_file':function(f){

        return Upload.upload({
            'method':'POST',
            'url': '/api/upload/'+f.name + '',
            'data': {'file': f}

        });
    }
```

Any idea?

**EDIT** I just saw that I have around 100 bytes appended at the begging and end of the file. The lines look like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryDiOIr9GGatp8GFBh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="hello.mp3"
Content-Type: audio/mp3

------WebKitFormBoundaryDiOIr9GGatp8GFBh--
```

Comment: what exactly is corrupted in the file? and what does your 'default_sorage.save()' do exactly?

Comment: it writes to the django default storage, which happens to be s3. But I tried to write manually to the filesystem, it is the same thing